# How to loop the items in script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've broke my head trying to find a pure CSS or JavaScript solution of how to loop my message items. As soon as all three messages are shown I want all of them to hide and appear again (one by one). Could you, please, help me mates? I'm not a guru in js so do not judge strictly please. Much appreciate in advance folks.

```css
:root {
  --msg-content-height: 26.75em;
  --msg-spacing: 1em;
  --msg1-height: 5.5em;
  --msg2-height: 4em;
  --msg3-height: 2.5em;
  --msg4-height: 2.5em;
  --msg5-height: 4em;
  --msg6-height: 3.25em;
}

.msg-send {
  position: absolute;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.msg-receive {
  position: absolute;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  background-color: #2d67ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.msg-container {
  width: 28em;
}

.msg-content {
  height: var(--msg-content-height);
}


/*Animation Names*/

#msg1 {
  animation-name: msg1;
}

#msg2 {
  animation-name: msg2;
}

#msg3 {
  animation-name: msg3;
}

#msg4 {
  animation-name: msg4;
}

#msg5 {
  animation-name: msg5;
}

#msg6 {
  animation-name: msg6;
}


/*Key Frames*/

@keyframes msg1 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height));
    left: -4em;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  5% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height));
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  12% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height));
  }
  17% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height));
  }
  30% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height));
  }
  35% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  49% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  54% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg1-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes msg2 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height));
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height));
    right: -4em;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  17% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height));
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height));
  }
  35% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  49% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  54% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
    right: 0;
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg2-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes msg3 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height));
    left: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  30% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height));
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  35% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height));
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  49% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height));
  }
  54% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg3-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg6-height));
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes msg4 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height));
    right: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  49% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height));
    right: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  54% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height));
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height));
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
    right: 0;
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg4-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg5-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes msg5 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height));
    left: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  70% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height));
    left: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  75% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height));
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height));
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg5-height) - var(--msg-spacing) - var(--msg6-height));
    left: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes msg6 {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: -4em;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  95% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(var(--msg-content-height) - var(--msg6-height));
    right: 0em;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="msg-container pv4 ph4 br3 center bg-white shadow-6">
        <div class="msg-content w-100 relative">
          <div id="msg1" class="msg-receive dib mb4 bg-message br4 pv2 ph3 white measure-narrow">Message #1</div>
          <div id="msg2" class="msg-send dib mb4 bg-near-white br4 pv2 ph3 mid-gray measure-narrow">Message #2 </div>
          <div id="msg3" class="msg-receive dib mb4 bg-message br4 pv2 ph3 white measure-narrow">Message #3</div>
     
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did't actually understand your concept of doing that but you can try **setInterval()** function as soon as page gets load to repeatedly call a function that can hide and show your content dynamically.

Here is the live example you can check : [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/np02xv14/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
showMessage();
    setInterval(function(){
  $(".msg-content").empty();
  showMessage(); }, 8000);
})
 function showMessage() {
            for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                $(".msg-content").append('<div id="msg' + i + '" class="msg-receive dib mb4 bg-message br4 pv2 ph3 white measure-narrow">"Message ' + i + '"</div>');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's almost what I've been looking for. But in your code the items go up for a while. How should I change the code so the after the third message appears, the whole box disappears and loop again.

Comment: I am glad to hear that worked for you. And answering to your question ,you can reduce the setInterval() function timeout to 7000(7s). This will disappears your box as soon as the thrid message appears.

Comment: Yep, but not quite working correctly. Please, see my comment above

Comment: Have to tried using 7000 millisecond timeout in setInterval() function?